Possible Issue in a Ring Decomposition Problem Involving $R_p$ Ideals
This is my homework on basic algebra, but I think there might be an issue with the problem.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. For any prime $p$, define
$$
R_p = \{ a \in R \mid p^n a = 0 \text{ for some integer } n \geq 0 \}.
$$
We are tasked with proving the following:

$R_p$ is an ideal of $R$.
There are only finitely many primes $p$ such that $R_p \neq \{0\}$. Moreover, if $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ are all the primes such that $R_{p_i} \neq \{0\}$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$, then
$$
R = R_{p_1} + \cdots + R_{p_k} \quad (+ \text{ denotes a direct sum}).
$$
For any ideal $I$ of $R$,
$$
R/I \cong \sum_{i=1}^k R_{p_i} / (R_{p_i} \cap I).
$$

However, consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}_2$. It is easy to see that $R_2 \neq \{0\}$. The identity element in $R$ is $(1, 1)$, so there is no integer $m$ such that $m \cdot (1, 1) = 0$ in $R$.
If we assume the second result is correct, the decomposition implies that $1 = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k$, where $a_i \in R_{p_i}$ and $p_i^{s_i} a_i = 0$ for some $s_i$. Then multiplying this equation by $\prod_i p_i^{s_i}$ yields $\prod_i p_i^{s_i} \cdot 1 = 0$, which is a contradiction.
Does this mean there is something wrong with the problem? Or am I misunderstanding something?

There's some conflicting notation here, but I am guessing that your example is for $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.
Ideals in such a product are products of ideals, so we see that the prime ideals of $R$ are
$$ P = p\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, \quad q = \{0\}\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, \quad r = \mathbb Z\times\{0\}. $$
Now $R_P$ consists of pairs $(a,b)\in R$ such that $aP^n=0=b$ for some $n$, so just $(0,0)$.
Similarly $R_q$ consists of those $(a,b)\in R$ such that $b=0$, and $R_r$ consists of those $(a,b)\in R$ with $a=0$.
This means that only $R_q$ and $R_r$ are non-zero, given by
$$ R_q = \mathbb Z\times\{0\} \cong \mathbb Z \qquad\textrm{and}\qquad R_r = \{0\}\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z. $$
We therefore (unsurprisingly) recover the decomposition
$$ R = R_q \oplus R_r \cong \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z. $$

So, the problem is wrong?

I want to say that the problem is wrong, because my case indicates that $R$ can't be written as direct sum of $R_{p_i}$, and in your answer, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not $R_p$.

No, I showed that for your example the question is correct. There are precisely two primes of $R$ which are non-zero, namely $q,r$ above, and $R$ is indeed the direct sum of $R_q$ and $R_r$.

But the definition of $R_p$ is not just prime ideal, the definition of $R_p$ is $R_p = { a \in R \mid p^n a = 0 \text{ for some integer } n \geq 0 }$. Obviously, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not right. Can you explain more?

$P$ consist of pairs $(px,y)$, so $P^n$ consists of pairs $(p^nx,y)$. Now $(a,b)$ is in $R_P$ provided $(a,b)P^n=0$, which is if and only if $a=0=b$, so $R_P=0$, as in the answer.

As I said earlier, the only primes where we obtain something nonzero are $q,r$. Then $R_q\cong\mathbb Z$ and $R_r\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

What is $q$ equal to? I know $r$ equals $2$, but I don't think there exists a prime $q$ such that $\mathbb{Z}\times{0}$ is isomorphic to $R_q$.

Oh, I see, but I think the prime in problem is prime number, not prime ideal.

In this example all the prime ideals are principal, so generated by a prime element. For the ideal $P$ we can take $(p,1)$, for $q$ we can take $(0,1)$, and for $r$ we take $(1,0)$.

I mean prime number in number theory.
